# iText Filling PDF Form password protected file, Allowed Filling: yes

Tags: c#, forms, pdf, itext

I have a PDF file with following Document Settings:

[I9 Form](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-9.pdf)

Document Settings:

[image: Document Settings]

When I create `PdfStamper (iText)` object it gives exception "`PdfReader not opened with owner password`". If we look into settings "`Form Field Fill-in or Signing: Allowed`", and we can manually fill this form.

How can we fill this form in C# using `iTextSharp` or any other tool.

Obviously I do not have Password.

Answer (score 2):

iText is *NOT* an end-user product. Instead iText is a library that gives you access to do whatever you want to do with a PDF file, assuming that you can open the document. The responsibility to obey the permissions set on the file lie with the developer.

To make sure developers are aware of this responsibility, it is not allowed to do anything with a PDF document if you don't have a password. You can work around this by changing a static variable in `PdfReader`: you need to set the parameter named `unethicalreading` to `true` (it's `false` by default).

From that moment on, you can do with the PDF whatever you want, and it's *your* responsibility to respect the permissions.

**Yes,** this does mean that setting permissions in a PDF using only an owner password is purely a psychological means to "protect" a document.

**No,** changing this parameter won't work if the PDF is protected with a user password (in which case you can't open the document without a password in Adobe Reader either).